# PHP session id not persist (no page reload)

Tags: php, session

The basic idea is that if the user logs in, they can add personalized events to their calendar.
Below is some basic logic of the code.

```
// Login.js
const Login = (props) => {
    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({loginusername: "", loginpassword: ""}) 
    // set a template of the user's login credential information: loginusername and loginpassword
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // getting data from the backend login.php
        const response = await fetch('http://...com:8000/Login.php', { 
            // recall: app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'cors',
            body: JSON.stringify({loginusername: credentials.loginusername, loginpassword: credentials.loginpassword}) 
            // setting up values obtained from the user's form
        });
        const json = await response.json()
        // const response = ...
        // const json = ... 
        console.log(json);
        if (json.success){ // if the user is successfully logged in 
            localStorage.setItem('token', json.authtoken);  
            setCredentials({ loginusername: "", loginpassword: "" });
            alert("Successfully Logged in!");
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid credentials");
        }
    }
```

```
//Login.php
<?php
// sends data to login.js
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://...com:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
session_start();
require 'database.php';

$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str, true);
//{"registerusername":"hello","password":"hello"}
//Variables can be accessed as such:
$user = $json_obj['loginusername'];
$current_pwd = $json_obj['loginpassword'];

// Use a prepared statement to retrieve user information
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*), ID, Username, HashedPassword FROM Users WHERE binary Username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cnt, $id, $loginusername, $pwd_hash);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
// Get the submitted loginpassword
// Compare the submitted loginpassword to the actual loginpassword hash
if ($cnt == 1 && password_verify($current_pwd, $pwd_hash)) {
    // Login succeeded
    // Record session variables
    $_SESSION['username'] = $loginusername;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    // Return success response as JSON
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Login successful', "username" => $_SESSION['username'], "id" => $_SESSION['id'], "phpSessionId" => session_id()));
} else {
    // Login failed; return error response as JSON
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Incorrect loginusername or loginpassword'));
}
?>
```

```
//AddEvent.js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // getting data from the backend AddEvent.php
        const response = await fetch("http://...:8000/AddEvent.php", { 
            // recall: app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({content: event.content, title: event.title, type: event.type}) 
            // setting up values obtained from the user's form
        });
        const json = await response.json()
        // const response = ...
        // const json = ... 
        console.log(json);
        if (json.success){ // if the user is successfully logged in 
            localStorage.setItem('token', json.authtoken);  
            setevent({ content: "", title: "", type: ""});
            alert("Successfully Added Event!");
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid event content");
        }
    }
```

```
//AddEvent.php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://...:3000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
session_start();
require 'database.php';
// Check if the form is submitted
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $userID = $_SESSION['id'];
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    // get the data from frontend 
    $content = $data['content'];
    $title = $data['title'];
    $type = $data['type'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO calendar (event_title, event_content, creator, event_type) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssis", $title, $content, $userID, $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    // add an event by executing 
    $response = [
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Event added successfully'
    ];
} else {
    $response = [
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Unauthorized access',
        'username' => $_SESSION['username'],
        "id" => $_SESSION['id'],
        'phpSessionId' => session_id()
    ];
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The problem is that after a user successfully logged in, the session does not persist. When I log the session ID and session username on the console, the console correctly logs the information of the session id and session username. However, when the user tries to add an event to the calendar, the session id and session username are both {null}
One specific example would be

When the user logs in:
{success: true, message: 'Login successful', username: 'bobby', id: 5, phpSessionId: 's1dfp2197id9n6n0d0pce5v5a0'}

When the user adds an event:
{success: false, message: 'Unauthorized access', username: null, id: null, phpSessionId: 'dtitrs2dm9mq9d0gk7ca5ot1dp'}

There is no page reload, and the user does not access different websites.

Comment: You need to use `credentials: 'include'` to make use of cookies. You also need specific session cookie configuration on the server-side to support cross-origin cookies